# how to show loader in react . using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using `axios` for `communicate` with server.I want to show loader when user request to server and  hide the loader when request is complete

So i make a custom component to do this task .but my UI hang when I click multiple times on same button

```
const Loader = () => {
    const { loadingCount } = useLoadingState(),
        {showLoading, hideLoading} = useLoadingActions();

    useEffect(()=>{
        const self = this
        axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
            showLoading();
            return config
        }, function (error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });

        axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
            // spinning hide
            // self.props.loading(false)
            hideLoading()
            return response;
        }, function (error) {
            hideLoading();
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
    })


    return (
        <div>
            {loadingCount > 0 ?<div style={{position:"fixed",display:"flex",justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center",width:'100%',height:'100%',zIndex:999999}}>
                {/*{loadingCount > 0 ? */}
                <Spin tip="Loading..." style={{zIndex:999999}}></Spin>
                {/*: null}*/}
            </div>: null}
        </div>





    );
};
```

**Problem is on `useeffect`**

when I comment out useEffect code it works perfectly .

**NoTe** : showloading and hideloading increase and decrease the loading count.

**I think I have deallocate axios object the when component is unmount**.???

Comment: There's no dependency array for the effect hook, so it is called every render. If the effect is updating state/props it could have a runaway effect. Hooks also only work with functional components, which there isn't an instance of, therefore, no `this`.

Answer (score 6):

Add empty array to sencod parameter to `useEffect`.
It works like `componentDidMount()` in functional component.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
    }, 3000);
  }, []); // here

  return (
    <div>
      {
        isLoaded &&
        <div>
          <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
          <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
            Click me
          </button>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i usualy use this code to show loading when request data is processing and hide when it's done

```js
const Loader = () => {
   const {data, setdata} = useState([])
  
    useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('your host').then(res => {
           setdata(res.data);        
        }).catch(err => {
          setdata(res.data);
        }
    });


    return (
        <div>
            {data.length > 0 
            ?
              <div style={{position:"fixed",display:"flex",justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center",width:'100%',height:'100%',zIndex:999999}}> </div>
             :
             <Spin tip="Loading..." style=        {{zIndex:999999}}>
             </Spin>
        </div>
    );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I created Loading components in shared folder. I am using Daisy UI, that's  why you have to first install tailwind & daisy otherwise it will not work. My Loading Code:

```
import React from 'react';

const Loading = () => {
    return (
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center ">
        <div className="w-16 h-16 border-b-2 border-gray-900 rounded-full animate-spin"></div>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Loading;
```

Then I am using this Loading component in my Allproduct component. For viewing Loading i created Reload useState.You will see below in my code, that will help my loader show when fetching time is very long.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Loading from '../Shared/Loading';
import AllProduct from './AllProduct';

const AllProducts = () => {
    const [products, setProduct]=useState([])
    const [Reload, setReload] = useState(true);

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('https://stormy-hamlet-97462.herokuapp.com/products/')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>{setProduct(data)
            setReload(false)})

    },[])

    if(Reload){
        return <Loading></Loading>
    }
    return (
        <div>
           <h4 className='text-4xl text-primary text-center sm:w-full px-32 mx-5 
           lg:my-12 '>All Products</h4>
             <div className='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-5'>
               {
                   products.map(product=><AllProduct key={product._id} product={product} ></AllProduct>)
               }

           </div>
            
        </div>
    );
};

export default AllProducts;
```